# node.js mongodb query in controller using MEAN stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

For this controller I am simply trying to return all the results of a collection.  There is one item in the prop collection but for some reason I keep getting an undefined error.

TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of undefined

This is my server.js file:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
passport = require('passport'),
logger = require('mean-logger');

   /**
 * Main application entry file.
 * Please note that the order of loading is important.
*/

// Initializing system variables
var config = require('./server/config/config');
var db = mongoose.connect(config.db);

// Bootstrap Models, Dependencies, Routes and the app as an express app
var app = require('./server/config/system/bootstrap')(passport, db);

// Return all results.
app.get('/all', function(req, res) {

  var d = db.prop.find();

  res.json(d);

});

// Start the app by listening on <port>, optional hostname
app.listen(config.port, config.hostname);

// Initializing logger
logger.init(app, passport, mongoose);

// Expose app
exports = module.exports = app;
```

Comment: If you are using passport/mongo - do you have any virtual schemas for mongoose...usually you do something like `User.find({})` to get all values - actually...maybe what u are doing is ok - but u might need `db.prop.find({});`

Comment: add the brackets inside the parentheses.

Comment: with mongoose the empty brackets signify "all" not "none" - a little counter-intuitive

Comment: While you don't need the empty braces, @ewizard is correct that you need to call `find` on your correct Mongoose model; so something like `Prop.find()`.

Comment: thanks guys, the issue is the collection is undefined for some reason.  db is defined but db.prop is undefined.  But in terminal in the mongo shell I can view the table and see the data.

Comment: you are not using mongoose correctly

Comment: you need to read up on mongoose schemas - it doesnt work like mysql queries.

Comment: you create a schema called `Prop` and then you import it when you need it - and call `Prop.find({})` or `Prop.find()` not sure which one

Answer (score 0):

Im going about this all wrong, Im used to js with restful controllers. Setting up the controller route in server.js is correct but making mongodb calls is actually done in the model level in the mean stack so this not working is as expected functionality. Basically you dont need ajax to query a mongo db.  Just not used to programming this way, thanks for feedback though.